# Two different object types as argument, returning objects of ones type

Tags: java, object

I've such problem - have one abstract class, and many classes that inherits from that class. I have function which gets as arguments objects of that non-abstract classes. It has to return object of non-abstract class, but I know which exectly in runtime. Any ideas?

Here sample code, how its looks like:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    int x, y;
    void foo();
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
    int r;
    void bar();
}

public class Square extends Shape {
    int a;
    void bar();
}
```

In both classes method bar() do the same thing. And now to do such thing:

```
/* in some other class */
public static Shape iHateWinter(Shape a, Shape b) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Shape result;

    /* 
     btw. my second question is, how to do such thing: 
     a.bar(); ?
    */

    if(rnd.nextInt(2) == 0) {
       /* result is type of a */
    } else {
       /* result is type of b */
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Well, you can't do `a.bar()`. Not until you define an abstract method `bar` in your `Shape` abstract class. Else compiler would complain that it cannot see any `bar()` method in the `Shape` class, because reference type of `a` is `Shape`. And Compiler is only worried about reference.

Answer (score 3):

put `public var abstract bar() {}` in the abstract class.

Then all children will have to implement `bar()`.

Then your if-block will be

```
if(rnd.nextInt(2) == 0) {
      return a;
    } else {
      return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be making things complicated for yourself.

```
/* 
 btw. my second question is, how to do such thing: 
 a.bar(); ?
*/
```

You add `bar()` to `Shape` and call `a.bar();`;

```
 if(rnd.nextInt(2) == 0) {
    /* result is type of a */
 } else {
    /* result is type of b */
```

This is fairly obtuse coding.  It's not clear why you would pass an object if you don't intend to use it. i.e. you only need it's class.

```
 result = rnd.nextBoolean() ? a.getClass().newInstance() : b.getClass().newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do a class cast.

```
if(a instanceof Circle)
{ Circle c = (Circle) a;
  c.bar();
}

if(a instanceof Square)
{ Square s = (Square) a;
  s.bar();
}
```